# Number of intersection points

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths, intersections, path-clipping

In this examle from pgfmanual p 132, how to use `\t` the number of intersections point outside `\fill` command. I tried `\def\Nb{\t}` but it dosen't work.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
\draw [name path=curve 1] (-2,-1) .. controls (8,-1) and (-8,1) .. (2,1);
\draw [name path=curve 2] (-1,-2) .. controls (-1,8) and (1,-8) .. (1,2);
\fill [name intersections={of=curve 1 and curve 2, name=i, total=\t}]
      [red, opacity=0.5, every node/.style={above left, black, opacity=1}]
      \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(i-\s) circle (2pt) node {\footnotesize\s}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use `\pgfextra{\xdef\Nb{\t}}` or `\pgfextra{\global\let\Nb\t}`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
  \draw [name path=curve 1] (-2,-1) .. controls (8,-1) and (-8,1) .. (2,1);
  \draw [name path=curve 2] (-1,-2) .. controls (-1,8) and (1,-8) .. (1,2);

  \path [name intersections={of=curve 1 and curve 2, name=i, total=\t}]
  \pgfextra{\xdef\Nb{\t}};

  \fill [red, opacity=0.5, every node/.style={above left, black, opacity=1}]
  \foreach \s in {1,...,\Nb}{(i-\s) circle (2pt) node {\footnotesize\s}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible also `\pgfextra{\global\let\t\t}`